# Restore by SQL-Script / wait for restore to finish

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-restore

In my script for restoring databases, I came to another problem. After restoring a database I want to edit some tables of it. So after the common restore query:

```
RESTORE DATABASE @DBname
FROM DISK = @BackupFileLocation
GO
```

I want to edit the mentioned tables. The problem is that I need to use some variables for editing the tables after the restore, that I declare before it (I need them there to). And it seems that `GO` kind of resets all variables so I can't use them afterwards. But if I try it without `GO`, it jumps over the restore query and says that the databases I want to edit, don't exist.

---

My Question: Is there another way to wait for the restore to finish until it continues editing the tables?

Comment: Pls use only the relevant product tags.

Comment: Are you running this script from SSMS? Are you replacing/overwriting an existing database, or does a database by that name not exist before the restore?

Comment: @PhilipKelley Yes I run this from SSMS. I don't replace/overwrite an existing database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s one way: set up a temp table (#table, not @variable), populate it with your values, then set your variables to these values. For example:

```
--  This will drop the temp table if it already exists.
--  Essential for repetitive testing!
IF object_id('tempdb.dbo.#Foo') is not null
    DROP TABLE #Foo
GO

CREATE TABLE #Foo
 (
   DBName              varchar(100)   not null
  ,BackupFileLocation  varchar(1000)  not null
 )

INSERT #Foo values ('MyDatabase', 'C:\SQL_Backups\SampleDBs')

DECLARE
  @DBname              varchar(100)
 ,@BackupFileLocation  varchar(1000)

SELECT
   @DBname             = DBName
  ,@BackupFileLocation = BackupFileLocation
 from #Foo


PRINT '--  Before restore  --------------------'
PRINT @DBname
PRINT @BackupFileLocation


--  Note: I did not test this statement
RESTORE DATABASE @DBname
 FROM DISK = @BackupFileLocation

GO

DECLARE
  @DBname              varchar(100)
 ,@BackupFileLocation  varchar(1000)

SELECT
   @DBname             = DBName
  ,@BackupFileLocation = BackupFileLocation
 from #Foo

PRINT ''
PRINT '--  After restore  --------------------'
PRINT @DBname
PRINT @BackupFileLocation

GO
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked quite well.
Only this part didn't work: 
`SELECT
   @DBname             = DBName
  ,@BackupFileLocation = BackupFileLocation
 from #Foo`
So I just changed it up to this:
`SET @DBname = (select DBName from #Foo)
SET @BackupFileLocation = (select BackupFileLocation from #Foo)`